# How to search within specific folders and files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I see in visual studio, i can search within:

1. Current Doc
2. Current Selection
3. All Open Docs
4. Current Project
5. Whole Solution

is there anyway to:

1. Search within certain file types (just javascript files, just .aspx files?) ?
2. Search within specific folders ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this using this options

[image]

You can also browse the folder the in which you want to perform the search using the button that is placed right to `Look in:` option.